# How to configure nginx to load my app webpage

Tags: nginx

I have configured this in nginx. When I enter my domain IP in the browser it will open the Nginx page. There should be my application webpage open. where I am going wrong and what I need to change here. Kindly guide

```
server {
       listen 80;

       server_name example.com;


      location / {

     
                proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass_request_headers on;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:80 https://example.com;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

                if ($request_method != GET) {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
                        break;
                }

                location /monitor
                {
                        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9000/monitor;

                }
                location / {
                         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                }
```

Comment: Do you visit `your domain` or `your IP` int the browser? Could you please add the `access.log` to the question?